# How to show that a map in $R^2$ is not fibration?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have
$E= [0,1]\times \{0\}\cup \{0\}\times [0,1]$  and the projection $p$ to the unit interval on the $x$ axis denoted by $B$. Now I have shown that this is a homotopy equivalence, and fibers of all $b\in B$ are contractible, but I am trying to show that this is not a fibration. I have tried to come up with some homotopies in B (eg. linear homotopy between constant map and identity) that can't be lifted but I can't seem to think of one.

Comment: Even sticking to paths, remember that being a fibration doesn't just tell you that you can lift the path. It tells you that for _any_ lift of the starting point, you find a lift of the path starting from that lift of the starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a one-point space, $h : P \times I \to B = I, h(*,t) = t$, and $f : P \to E, f(*) = (0,1)$. Then $p \circ f = h  \circ i_0$, where $i_0 : P \to P \times I, i_0(*) = (*,0)$. There is no lift $H : P \times I \to E$ of $h$ such that $H \circ i_0 = f$.